# What to change the variable below to?

Tags: php

I have a destination variable where when I upload a file then it goes to this destination:

```
<?php
   // Edit upload location here
   $destination_path = getcwd().DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;

   $result = 0;

   $target_path = $destination_path . basename( $_FILES['fileImage']['name']);

   if(@move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileImage']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
      $result = 1;
   }

   sleep(1);
?>
```

What I want to know is how do I edit the upload destination? Lets say I want the files to upload to the destination to go to portal.hud.ac.uk/Upload_App/Files/ then how do I change this?

Comment: `$destination_path` is your target directory. Seems your code is copy paste from somewhere. there is a very clear comment. `//Edit your upload location here`

Comment: C'mon... really? Changing a variable's value is an utterly basic skill in ANY language...

Comment: The code is given when you open the zip file for the uploaded. Anyway MArc B, I am guessing when you was younger learning programming there were things you didn't know and you ask questions so don't undermine me and saying it is easy and all that rubbish. I asked for an answer not a stupid comment

Answer (score 2):

Just change `$destination_path` to whatever you want. The way it is now (`getcwd().DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`), it will save to the current working folder (which unless changed is the folder containing the script). This is very unsafe because I could just upload a file called `index.php` and anyone visiting your site would run whatever malicious code I would choose to insert.

Much safer would be to save it outside the webroot, where it can't be accessed directly via HTTP. Example:

```
$destination_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/../uploads/";
```

This will save to a folder called `uploads` found in the folder that contains the web root (probably `public_html`).

Comment: So just to clarify, if I have a folder known as "uploads_app" where the script is based in and in that folder is a folder known as "uploads", then the code above would send the file to that folder?